# AES String Encryption/Decryption

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I'm new to Encryptions. I'm finding codes about encryption and i'm trying to know how it is working because it's interesting and I like to code it in the future.

Then I found this code:

```
  System.out.print("Enter text: ");
      String text = dataIn.readLine();
      String key = "Bar12345Bar12345"; // 128 bit key

       // Create key and cipher
     Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
     Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
 ...
```

Before I start working on it. I don't know how `String = Bar12345Bar12345` works. It says that it is `128 bit key`. Is the `String` constant? Is it okay to change it?

Comment: The string is 18 ASCII characters long, so the bit length is 18*8 bit = 128 bit. It's the secret key to encrypt/decrypt, so you should keep it secret.

Comment: So is it okay to change it as long as it's length is 16?

Comment: This is only simple example - you should use some hash function to generate key from password (not key.getBytes()). The hash will give you the key with correct length.

Comment: What do you mean by `hash function`? Sorry i'm beginner in Encryption.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be precise, the string is not your key, but the bytes you get from `key.getBytes()`. While it may work for this sample, this is not something you should do in production code:

- getBytes() may convert the string to different bytes if a different charset is used (unlikely for your specifc string, since it is ASCII only, but something you have to be aware of).
- You need a string of correct length.
- The quality of the generated key will be quite poor. For production code you should use a key derivation function like pbkdf2 to derive a key from something like a password.

There is another issue: Instead of just using "AES" you should also specify the mode of operation and padding when constructing your Cipher object (e.g. "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"). Otherwise the second and third parameter are provider dependent.